# Convert FoxPro Program File to Java

Tags: java, converters, foxpro

Is there any converting tool, that can convert syntax of FOX PRO 2.0 program files to Java syntax? Something like:

```
IF nTimeStamp = 0
RETURN "Not built into App"
ENDIF
```

convert to for example

```
if(nTimeStamp == 0 )
System.out.println("Not built into App");
```

I need to rewrite application made in FoxPro to Java and looking for easy way how to quickly understand FoxPro syntax without long study. I'm just looking for syntax convertor and not JDBC drivers for reading data from FoxPro DBF files. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

5 seconds on Google yields [VFP2Java](http://www.vfp2java.net/) ...which is for Visual FoxPro, but might help since the old FoxPro 2.0 syntax is still almost all supported.

I have a lot of Fox experience, and some Java (and a lot of .NET, which is, er, Java-esque), and I'd say that while you might get some distance in terms of pure program code with a tool like that, you'd still be in the dark when the tool fails on elements like screens, because the bottom line is you don't know any FoxPro 2.0, and you don't want to learn, which is fair enough. There is a correlation with things like basic program flow (loops, conditionals) and even declarations, functions and so on. But how do you translate something like this into Java?

```
Open Database MyDatabase Shared
Update myTable where x=y set field1='this', field2='that'
Close All
```

Are you connecting to the FoxPro tables with JDBC? Are you connecting to Postgres or something? What ORM are you using ? These sort of questions pop up.

Comment: Good points about the screens and data access, though OPEN DATABASE didn't exist in 2.x

Comment: Guys, you didnt catch the point. I'm **not** looking for program that transform FoxPro to Java with GUI, tables and everything. I'm just looking for **syntax convertor**, something, that would help me to understand the syntax, the FOXPRo language, the algorithms used in program. I will redesign all GUI and make tables from scratch. I thing the fastest way is to study some FoxPro tutorial with basicss. I used such a converter that translate from C++ to Java and it works perfectly. I used it on a pure code, algorithms, rewriting loops and these kind of stuff. Anyway, thank you for your time.